# Разименование итератора в std::set

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! 
Я недавно начал заниматься программированием и сейчас возникла потребность в рассмотрении контейнера std::set(далее именуемый контейнер). И у меня возникло несколько вопросов, поискав в интернете не нашел подходящих ответов, решил спросить у знающих людей, которые могли бы помочь мне. И так суть вопроса, имеется контейнер типа const char* в который мы добавляем 2 элемента.

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_set<const char*> unordered_set;
    unordered_set myUnorderedSet;
    myUnorderedSet.insert("testAction");
    myUnorderedSet.insert("testActionTwo");
```

далее если пробежаться по контейнеру

```
for ( unordered_set::iterator it = myUnorderedSet.begin(); it != myUnorderedSet.end(); ++it ) {
     std::cout << " " << *it;
     std::cout << std::endl;        
        }
```

можно вывести значения хранящиеся в данном контейнере. Затем я пытаюсь найти нужное мне значение используя метод find().

```
unordered_set::iterator = myUnorderedSet.find("testAction");
```

Как получить значение данного итератора, для того чтобы можно было сравнить его со значение которое я добавлял в контейнер*? И почему при такой записи

> *iter

я получаю ошибку компиляции: **list iterator is not dereferencable**.  Не совсем понимаю, ведь

```
for ( unordered_set::iterator it = myUnorderedSet.begin(); it != myUnorderedSet.end(); ++it ) {
             std::cout << " " << *it;
             std::cout << std::endl;        
                }
```

мы можем применить операцию разыменования. Заранее благодарен за ответы!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

смотрим описание метода `find()` [тут(ru)](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) или [тут(en)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) и видим что если `find` ничего не находит то возвращает итератор на `end()`, то есть на элемент **следующий за последним** и он (итератор `end()`) действительно не разыменуемый (is not dereferencable)

то есть имея массив из 5 элементов `[0,1,2,3,4]` `find` ненайдя ничего вернёт `[5]` то есть `end()`

соответственно для проверки "а нашлось ли чего нибудь" сравниваем if(iterator==myUnorderedSet.end())

---

---

---

**почему так происходит?**

в set'e вы храните **не строку**  `testAction` а указатель на неё и в функции `find()` сравниваются указатели!

когда вы пишите строку в хардкоде то она помещается в специально отведённое **место** в программе, а вместо неё используется указатель на это **место**, написав два раза одинаковую строку `testAction` получаем две строки в специально отведённом **месте** (**НО** компиляторы могут с оптимизировать такие строки, в итоге имеем **UB**)

---

---

---

**как сравнивать строки?**

в STL есть тип данных(class) для строк [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) пихаем строки в стринг и при сравнении будет происходить преобразование

```
string str="hello world";// или string str("hello world");
if(str=="hello world")//TRUE
```

Comment: С этим я ознакомился, но ведь я используя метод find() ищу myUnorderedSet.find("testAction"); тот ключ который положил ранее myUnorderedSet.insert("testAction"). Каким  образом он его не может найти, или я что не понимаю?

Comment: @Nuri  дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения. Вроде стало все на свои места.